# Ubuntu 18.04 Booting from USB causing weird screen

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, usb

I'm trying to dual boot to ubuntu with windows. I followed the guide [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) to make a ubuntu 18.04 bootable usb.

It shows the options to try, install, oem, and check for defects. When I click on any it causes the screen below. I have tried redoing the usb, but the same error. I also tried opening the GRUB menu described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170948/weird-screen-when-i-attempt-to-boot-ubuntu-from-a-usb-hard-drive) but it also causes this screen. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Edit: Here is the command-line I'm using with the possible commands.
[image]

Comment: Did you try `nomodeset`?

Comment: I got the grub command-line, but it says `error: can't find command nomodeset`

Comment: Add it to the `linux` line of the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` menuentry, similar to: linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash `nomodeset` persistent ---"

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any text editor to use, I'm not sure how I can add it.

Comment: Ah I figured out what you meant. Thanks!